# What's the most natural way to say "we broke up"?

Tags: choix-de-mot

I would like to say "she and I broke up". One way to say this is *elle et moi avons rompu*. Is this the most natural way of expressing the concept of a romantic breakup?

Comment: "Plaquer" can be used when insisting on who made to decision to break up : Je l'ai plaquée.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***Nous*** is almost unused as a subject in modern spoken French, so what is more likely to be heard is:

- *Elle et moi, **on** a rompu* (but *rompu* is slightly formal)
- *..., on s'est séparés / on s'est quittés*
- *Elle et moi, c'est fini*
- *Entre nous, c'est fini* / *c'est fini entre nous*
- *Avec elle, c'est fini*
- *On a cassé* (as Greg wrote, this is more a teenager/young adults vocabulary)

And if  you want a "romantic" tone to say it:

- *Nos chemins se sont séparés...*

Comment: never heard "on a cassé", may it be specific to Quebec?

Comment: @AnneAunyme I don't know about a Quebec usage but that's definitely a common expression among teenagers at least in South-East France. A quick search shows it is also referenced as a *Pied-Noir* expression (Le parler des Pieds Noirs d'Oran et d'Oranie: *As qui paraît que Myriam elle a cassé avec son fiancé*).

Comment: @AnneAunyme Se dit aussi en région parisienne.

Answer (score 2):

"Nous avons rompu" is indeed a good translation, it conveys the same meaning.

You may think of some alternatives such as:

"Nous nous sommes quittés"

"Nous nous sommes séparés" (I would rather use it for a couple that lived together)

"Nous avons cassé" (this one is more colloquial, it would be used by younger people)

Comment: Merci! Ce sont utiles.

Comment: Watch out, you should say "c'est utile", or "ces alternatives/ces réponses sont utiles", or even "elles sont utiles" ("elles" would then refer to "alternatives"), but not *ce sont utiles. I am not sure what the rule is for using "ce" for a plural, maybe it should be another question...

Comment: « Nous nous sommes séparés », ok. « Nous avons rompu », à la rigueur. Mais « nous avons cassé » ??? Non, « on a cassé ».

Answer (score 1):

Tout d'abords, Bonsoir. Je vis en France depuis 10 ans et c'est comme ma deuxième langue natale. Pour répondre à ta question je vais me baser sur mon vécu :
Si tu veux le dire d'une façon plus "romantique" comme tu le dis tu devras dire : 
Nous avons décidés de rompre
ou comme tu le pense "Elle et moi avons rompu" est un excellent choix aussi.

J'espère avoir été utile. Bonne soirée

Comment: Merci, monsieur, tu as été très utile. +1 Bon soir!